# how to establish connection between ADLS and kafka to process the files/data in databricks/ADF

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-data-lake

we are having a source which are producing streaming data into ADLS path,
need a solution to connect ADLS with kafka and use the streaming data processing in databricks/ADF.
How to achieve this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Azure Data Lake Gen2 connector for Kafka only support sink. You can export data from Apache Kafka to ADLS Gen 2 in `Avro`, `JSON`, `Parquet` and `ByteArray`.

Depending on your configuration, the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 connector can export data by guaranteeing exactly-once delivery semantics to consumers of the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 files it produces.

You can refer the confluent document [Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 Sink Connector for Confluent Platform](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-azure-data-lake-gen2-sink/current/overview.html).